# When someone sells his RAM to another account, how it would clear from previous contracts?

Tags: ram, ram-allocation, cpu, ramcore

I know unlike CPU and Net bandwidth, RAM ***doesn't refresh itself***.
we also know that we can exchange our RAM with EOS. But when someone sell his RAM to anoher user. So in this case what happen how  producers clears RAM?

I am little confused here with above two statement.

*Let me know if this question is suitable to ask over here.*

Comment: you can't sell allocated ram. you need to free your ram before selling-it's not the producers who do that

Comment: So for that I have to remove all tables and codes from my contracts?

Comment: if it's your contract that uses your ram, you need to update it to delete the entries in the multi index for which you paid or change the payee. if it's someone else's contract, they need to expose an action that allows you to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

confused00 should have made this response as he/she is correct.

RAM must be freed before you can sell it.

For a dev this means you have to release your claim on the RAM to sell it

For an end user this means you need to see how the application you're dealing with has consumed your RAM and execute the command that is hopefully there to "free" that RAM so that you may sell your RAM.